# text box to contain selected preference string

Tags: android, string, layout

Using Android Studio... I have a settings page where users select from a string of values from an XML preference resource. Once that string has been selected my app refreshes.

Im struggling with the main page where I want a subtitle to update with the selected string from the settings page... can anyone help?

**This is my subtitle text box...**

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:text="subtitle" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

**This is my preference section I want to copy from**

```
       <ListPreference
        android:title="@string/notifications_feed_url"
        android:key="feed_url"
        android:entries="@array/rssNames"
        android:entryValues="@array/rssFeeds"
        android:defaultValue="News"/>
```